# Random Forest Regressor Overfitting

Tags: regression, python, overfitting

I'm implementing a Random Forest Regressor using Random Forest algorithm in scikit-learn. Please consider the following performance in terms of RMSE:

```
 RMSE Train: 33.67
 RMSE Test : 88.01
```

The prediction performance seems to be very good, but I would know if such an algorithm, according to the performances expressed in RMSE considering both Train and Test, is in overfitting.

More in general, do you think that it is overfitting?
The second question, is there a sort of difference between train and test error to establish overfitting?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The numbers don't make much sense on their own. For ex, what is the mean & deviation of the target variable?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The STD of train : 282; STD of test: 286. Do you suggest me a general rule to identify the overfitting?

Comment: For instance, if I optimize the hyperparams (max_depth and min_samples_leaf) with grid search I obtain the RMSE train: 85 and RMSE test: 101 with STD train: 271 and STD test 279.

Comment: I'd advise you to replace training performance with OOB score. This gives a more reliable estimate of the model performance (as a random forest by construction overfits on the training data).

Comment: @MichaelM the oob is 0.56. How should I check the overfitting with such a parameter?